# Is NReco pdf generator supported in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created a C# Azure function for pdf generation and am using the NReco pdf generator, but it is not working on Aazure.

Could you please suggest a method to make it run in azure?

I have installed NReco Pdf generator through NuGet Package Manager Console and I am getting the following error:

> "Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.12599\wkhtmltopdf' is denied.

This is the stacktrace of exception that is thrown:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
at NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.EnsureWkHtmlLibs()
at NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdfInternal(WkHtmlInput[] htmlFiles, String inputContent, String coverHtml, String outputPdfFilePath, Stream outputStream)
at NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdfFromFile(String htmlFilePath, String coverHtml)
at VRProductions.Repository.PdfGenerationRepository.<SendMail>d__1.MoveNext()
```

This is the code am using for pdf generation:

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile(blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri, "");
```

Comment: *"No working"* isn't a *technical description* of a problem

Answer (score 1):

I am able to generate pdf using following function code..see if this of any help.. Azure functions V1

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp41
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


            var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
            var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("<file_path_including_sas_token>", "");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(pdfBytes));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

if you run this function locally from visual studio..file will be generated and pdf will be loaded in browser or asked to save.

```
http://localhost:7071/api/Function1
```

Comment: This is the same am using and still i get this error.

Comment: please see this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ae5d349-8083-4bd5-a8b3-e2100be330de/dll-permission-in-azure-function-environment?forum=AzureFunctions). I tried this but still not works

Comment: will give a try on Azure..I haven't tried deploying on Azure